# Xampp no carga proyecto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp, macos

Tengo el proyecto **laravel** en un mac con OSX el capitán con **php artisan**. El proyecto se ejecuta sin problema, pero por motivos personales quiero utilizar el apache de xampp en ves de artisan server entonces cuando trato de cargar el *index.blade.php* en ves de cargar la vista aparece esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realice el mismo procedimiento pero en una pc con Windows 7 y el XAMPP carga sin ningún problema mi App no se por que razón en el Mac no corre ¿alguna idea?

la url que intento acceder es

> http://localhost/sisVentas/resources/views/almacen/categoria/index.blade.php

el archivo route.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php

/*
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

/*
Route::get('crearusuario',function(){
  return "URL crearusuarioasdadasd";
});
*/

//carpeta dentro de VISTAS almacen
Route::resource('almacen/categoria','CategoriaController');
```

lo curioso es que cuando intento acceder simplemente a localhost con el xampp en ves de cargar la bienvenida de laravel aparece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si puedes poner el url al que estas ingresando y el código de tu archivo routes.

Comment: ya lo agrege al post :)

Comment: Para poder acceder a laravel no es la ruta que s}pusiste debe ser de esta manera ***http://localhost/sisVentas/public***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.- Estas accediendo a la ruta equivocada.Para poder acceder laravel deber de ir a la carpeta public que es ahi donde te cargara todo.

```
http://localhost/sisVentas/public
```

2.- Otra opcion es configurar los host virtuales de tu Xampp para que puedas acceder a esos proyecto de una forma mas facil.
Para hacer eso es muy sencillo

**Configurar windows host**

1. Abre el bloc de notas como administrador
2. Abres el archivo ***hosts*** ubicado en ***C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc***
3. Te aparecera la resolucion de nombres de tu host agrega esta linea ***  127.0.0.1   sisventas.com***, o como quieras llamarle a tu dominio virtual

---

**Configurar httpd-vhosts de Xampp**

1. Desde el mismo bloc de notas abres el archivo **httpd-vhosts** ubicado en **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra**
2. Agregas lo siguiente

   `<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sisVentas/public/"
   ServerName sisventas.com

   </VirtualHost>`
3. Reinicia el servicio de xammp y podras acceder a la ruta sisVentas.com directamente

**NOTA:** las rutas en host de mac van a variar tal es el caso en la ruta de Hosts para mac es **/etc/hosts** y para la ruta en xampp es dependiendo donde este ubicado tu xampp

Comment: gracias por la información problema solucionado un saludo :D

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma para acceder a una ruta mas correctas directa con tu app de Laravel es ejecutando el comando `serve`

Te daré un ejemplo con Windows...

**-** Abrir la consola de window(CMD)

**-** Ir a la ruta de tu app mediante la consola(**cd C:/xampp/htdocs/miAppenLaravel**)

**-** Ejecutar el comando `php artisan serve`

**-** Ir al navegador y entrar a la ruta dada por el comando anterior ("localhost:8000")

Comment: Pero aqui se requiere mandar a produccion, el cliente no va estar ejecuantando ese comando cadavez que se le apague el equipo

Answer (score 0):

No se que version de Laravel estás usando para trabajar, pero en OSX ya trae un mini servidor interno que te permite correr el proyecto sin tener que configurar el Apache, para instalar el complemento debes de hacer lo siguiente en la terminal:

```
~$composer global require laravel/valet
```

Luego de eso ejecutas lo siguiente siempre en la terminal:

```
~$valet install
~$cd sisVentas
~/sisVentas$valet link
```

Luego vas al navegador y podras abrir el proyecto a travez de un dominio local parecido a esto:

```
http://sisventas.dev/
```

todo eso sin hacer nada más que un par de configuraciones y tendrás listo tu miniservidor local sin configurar apache ni herramientras adicionales.